# Unit test with promises: How to mock $q or know deferred has been called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service

I have a service that are using promises. Here is a simplified example of my service:

```
angular.module('myService').service('popup', [
    '$q', function(
     $q ) {

    this.alert = function(myValue) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (myValue = 0) {
            deferred.resolve('myValue is null');
        } else {
            deferred.reject('myValue isn\'t null');
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

I would like a unit test like:

- Given: myValue = 0
- When: myService.alert()
- Then: deferred.resolve has been called

The problem is, I understand since 'deferred' is a var inside my service, I can't access it in my unit tests (to mock it). So I need to mock $q, and I don't have any idea how to do that (I've tried some ways without success).

Anyone know how I can mock $q or know if deferred.resolve() has been called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not mock $q, too much work.

I would do something like :

```
it('Should be resolve when myValue is 0', function (){

    //given myValue = 0
    var myValue = 0;
    // calling myService.alert
    var promise = myService.alert(myValue);

    var resolved = false;
    promise.then(function (success){
       resolved = true; 
    }, function (error){

    });
    //actually resolve the promise
    $rootScope.$digest();

    //expect promise to have been resolved
    expect(resolved).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
If someone got the same problem: I was on the wrong way, more focused on "how to know my service has executed deferred.resolve" than "how to know my service has executed the code into 'then' && return a success or false promise (I resolved the 2nd part by adding an other test).